# network request failed when running expo app on android device

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, expo

[image: Screenshot of my expo xde witht the error logs on the right.]

I am using a localhost server for my app development on expo. I get this error on my android device.
My server and api works fine as I have tested it on postman. It works well in the browser too. I am already using my ip address in the fetch function instead of localhost.
The fetch also works fine on genymotion android emulator. The issue is only on my actual android device.

Thanks

Comment: Is your device on the same network that is your computer?

Comment: yes, it is on the same network. If it were not I won't have been able to open the app. The issue is the network call.

Comment: can you try to make the request using the browser on your device?

Comment: No, I am not able to make the request on my android device's browser but yes I can make a request on my host device's browser

Comment: Can nginx be any issue ?

Comment: can you try ping from your computer to your device? ping from terminal

Comment: yes, I am able to ping

Comment: I get the issue, I am not able to access my localhost server from any other device even though they are on the same network

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue finally. The issue was my firewall(ufw) which was not allowing access for public ports.
sudo ufw allow from 192.xxx.x.xxx to any port 80 helped me as it allows acces to publicly open ports.

Thanks